# A Python-to-PHP compatible AES encryption with openssl_encrypt AES-CBC

Tags: php, python-3.x, encryption, interop, aes

I have a Python application and PHP website that communicate over some specific network layer sending messages. My task is to send all messages AES-encrypted and base64-encoded using that channel. Encryption key is pre-shared for both parties manually.

In my PHP, i used this code to create final message text called `$payload`:

```
 $key = substr('abdsbfuibewuiuizasbfeuiwhfashgfhj56urfgh56rt7856rh', 0, 32);
 $magic = 'THISISANENCRYPTEDMESSAGE';

 function crypted($data) {
      global $key, $magic;

       // serialize
       $payload = json_encode($data);

       // encrypt and get base64 string with padding (==):
       $payload = @openssl_encrypt($payload, 'AES-192-CBC', $key);

       // prepend with magic
       $payload = $magic.$payload;
       return $payload;
    }
```

And i receive such message in my Python application, stripping the magic, getting base64 byte data. The problem that i cannot find a sample to make  compatible AES cipher to decode this message.

Key and "Magic" are only values pre-shared and known on both sides, is this correct? Do i need an IV?

Here is Python solution from SO that does not work for my crypted messages.

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class AESCipher:

    class InvalidBlockSizeError(Exception):
        """Raised for invalid block sizes"""
        pass

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.iv = bytes(key[0:16], 'utf-8')

    def __pad(self, text):
        text_length = len(text)
        amount_to_pad = AES.block_size - (text_length % AES.block_size)
        if amount_to_pad == 0:
            amount_to_pad = AES.block_size
        pad = chr(amount_to_pad)
        return text + pad * amount_to_pad

    def __unpad(self, text):
        pad = ord(text[-1])
        return text[:-pad]

    def encrypt( self, raw ):
        raw = self.__pad(raw)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
        return b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt( self, enc ):
        enc = b64decode(enc)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv )
        r = cipher.decrypt(enc)  # type: bytes
        return self.__unpad(r.decode("utf-8", errors='strict'))
```

It fails on last line with decode problem. "ignore" decoding mode returns empty string.

```
# with magic: "THISISANENCRYPTEDMESSAGE8wZVLZpm7UNyUf26Kds9Gwl2TBsPRo3zYDFQ59405wI="
# contains: {'test': 'hello world'}
payload = '8wZVLZpm7UNyUf26Kds9Gwl2TBsPRo3zYDFQ59405wI='

aes = AESCipher('abdsbfuibewuiuizasbfeuiwhfashgfh')
print(aes.decrypt(payload))
```

Raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "../test.py", line 36, in decrypt
    return self.__unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc).decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 0: invalid start byte
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Why are you using `text[-1]` (a `x02` byte, so you are ignoring the last 2 bytes) to determine how long the encrypted data string is?

Comment: Using the key as the IV is a really not smart idea.  Like really not smart.  And having a key made entirely of ASCII letters and numbers reduces the possible keyspace significantly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [Cipher Block Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CBC), but didn't pass in an IV to `openssl_encrypt()`; this means the IV is then 16 times the NUL byte. But your Python code uses the *key* as the IV instead, so that'll produce a different decryption result altogether.

Next, you picked `AES-192-CBC`, not `AES-256-CBC`, so only 192 bits are used for the key. 192 bits == 24 bytes, and *not* 32 as you thought.

You also need to drop the `__unpad()` call entirely, there is no padding in your encrypted data, removing data from the end before decrypting will only lead to the decryption failing.

So to decrypt on the Python side, use 24 characters for the key, give an IV that is 16 times `\x00`, and pass in *all* data you decoded from Base64:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> from base64 import b64decode
>>> key = 'abdsbfuibewuiuizasbfeuiwhfashgfh'[:24]
>>> key
'abdsbfuibewuiuizasbfeuiw'
>>> payload = '8wZVLZpm7UNyUf26Kds9Gwl2TBsPRo3zYDFQ59405wI='
>>> enc = b64decode(payload)
>>> cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, '\x00' * 16)
>>> cipher.decrypt(enc)
b'{"test":"hello world"}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'
```

If you wanted to use the full 32 characters of the key, use AES-256-CBC instead.

You really want to produce a random IV, so that someone snooping on the traffic can't determine patterns (where the same payload produces the same encrypted message each time). Generate the IV, include it in the data you send, and extract it on the Python side to pass to the `AES.new()` function.