# AES-256-CBC encryption returning different result in Python and PHP , HELPPP

Tags: python, php, encryption, aes

Python Code:

```py
     from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
     from Crypto.Cipher import AES
     from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
     import base64

     def encrypt_string(input_string, key_base64, str_iv):
         try:
            key = key_base64.encode('utf-8')
        
            if str_iv:
               iv = base64.b64decode(str_iv)
            else:
               iv = get_random_bytes(16)

            cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
            padded_data = pad(input_string.encode(), AES.block_size)
            cipher_data = cipher.encrypt(padded_data)
            combined_data = iv + cipher_data
            return base64.b64encode(combined_data).decode()

         except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        key = "1bd393e7a457f9023d9ba95fffb5a2e1"
        iv = "1oTOhV9xGyu1mppmWZWa5w=="
        input_string = "AAAAAAA"
        encrypted_data = encrypt_string(input_string, key, iv)
        print("Encrypted string:", encrypted_data)`
```

OUTPUT :
Encrypted string: 1oTOhV9xGyu1mppmWZWa5+kzveiTRzRH+gRVHx+7Ad0=

PHP code:

```php
      <?php
       function encrypt_string($input_string, $key_base64, $str_iv) {
        try {
         $key = base64_decode($key_base64);

        if ($str_iv) {
            $iv = base64_decode($str_iv);
        } else {
            $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        }
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($input_string, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $combined_data = $iv . $ciphertext;
        return base64_encode($combined_data);
       } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
       }
      }
      $key = "1bd393e7a457f9023d9ba95fffb5a2e1";
       $iv = "1oTOhV9xGyu1mppmWZWa5w==";
       $input_string = "AAAAAAA";
       $encrypted_data = encrypt_string($input_string, $key, $iv);
       echo "Encrypted string: " . $encrypted_data . "\n";
      ?>
```

OUTPUT:
Encrypted string: 1oTOhV9xGyu1mppmWZWa53Nc8rxWTultBWLvWitUICQ=

Please, does anyone know how to make the output of these two codes the same?

Comment: I am going to strongly recommend that you upgrade from the `pycrypto` package to the `cryptography` package.

Comment: i tried and it didn't solve the problem

Comment: `base64.b64encode(combined_data).decode()` seems wrong. Do you really want it decoded? Your PHP isn't doing that.

Comment: I think my Python code is wrong, because the function doesn't do anything, but the results are what I want, not with the PHP code

Comment: Have you see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40820661/231316?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the same result then just remove the `$key = base64_decode($key_base64)`. I did get the right result for `$key = $key_base64`.

---

Note that using the base64 encoding directly as key means that a maximum of 6 bits contain random information for each character / byte of input. So if you insert 32 characters then the key size is effectively 32 * 6 = 192 bits. That's more than enough, but clearly less than the 256 bits "promised" by AES-256.

The other issue is that CBC doesn't offer integrity / authenticity.

---

I'd recommend never to convert keys to strings in the first place - just keep them binary. Furthermore, if you're going to encrypt with a symmetric key then use something like NaCL or another library that performs higher level "sealing" rather than just encryption. If you want to use a password then you should use a good Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF) such as PBKDF2 or Argon2.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your PHP code.  The `openssl_encrypt` function takes a `passpharse` argument:

> If the passphrase is shorter than expected, it is silently padded with NUL characters; if the passphrase is longer than expected, it is silently truncated.

For AES 256, this should be 32 characters. Your `$key` variable is getting padded with `\null` bytes.

The difference is in the first line of each function.

In your Python code, this just converts the ASCII key from a string to bytes.  Since the length of the initial key is 32, this is fine.

```py
    key = key_base64.encode('utf-8')
```

In your PHP, this decodes the from base 64 back to bytes, which shortens the key to 24 bytes.

```php
    $key = base64_decode($key_base64);
```

To make the Python code the same as the PHP code, you would need to do:

```py
key = base64.b64decode(key)
```

However, this will fail later on in the code in Python because the length of the key is only 24, and Python does not silently pad the key.

One work around is to use a hash of the key for the passphrase and truncate it to 32 characters.  Keep in mind this is NOT a good security practice, see @maarten-bodewes comment below.  Here are examples in Python and PHP.  I removed the exception handling for simplicity.

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.algorithms import AES256
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.padding import PKCS7
import hashlib
import base64


def encrypt_string(input_string: str, key: bytes, iv: bytes):
    # the key must be of length 32
    key_hash = hashlib.sha256(key).digest()[:32]
    cipher = Cipher(AES256(key_hash), modes.CBC(iv))
    pad = PKCS7(AES256.block_size).padder()
    
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    cipher_data = encryptor.update(
        pad.update(input_string.encode('utf-8')) 
        + pad.finalize()
    )
    combined_data = iv + cipher_data
    return base64.b64encode(combined_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    key = b'password'
    iv = b'aaaabbbbccccdddd'
    input_string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    encrypted_data = encrypt_string(input_string, key, iv)
    print("Encrypted string:", encrypted_data.decode())

# prints:
# Encrypted string: YWFhYWJiYmJjY2NjZGRkZALrlaYfFmHrO6FOv64BdVueK/yYNjjgtdQx+A0eR9iv
```

And the PHP code:

```php
<?php
function encrypt_string($input_string, $key, $iv) {
    // take the first 32 characters, just to be explicit
    $key_hash = substr(hash('sha256', $key, true), 0, 32);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
        $input_string, "aes-256-cbc", $key_hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv
    );
    $combined_data = $iv . $ciphertext;
    return base64_encode($combined_data);
}

$key = 'password';
$iv = "aaaabbbbccccdddd";
$input_string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$encrypted_data = encrypt_string($input_string, $key, $iv);
echo "Encrypted string: " . $encrypted_data . "\n";
?>

// echos:
// Encrypted string: YWFhYWJiYmJjY2NjZGRkZALrlaYfFmHrO6FOv64BdVueK/yYNjjgtdQx+A0eR9iv
```

Comment: If a password is going to be used then an PBKDF such as PBKDF2 or Argon2 should be used. Just hashing a key is not enough. Some kind of protection against weak passwords should also be present. Either that or the `$key` must be a real key, not a passphrase, in which case it should be 16, 24 or 32 fully random(ized) bytes.

Comment: I believe this is just a toy example that the original author was struggling with.  I will add a note about security as well.

Comment: if i can't change the py code , do u have recommend what should i do ?

Comment: Fix your PHP code.  That was the issue.

Comment: thanks guys , already fix it , May you all be blessed with good fortune and success